# Accessing US Social Security from Overseas

Tags: location

I am a US citizen who will be overseas for an extended period of time. From what I've read, it seems that US Social Security website will not allow users to access their Social Security information from an overseas IP address. This can be frustrating! Can Tor Browser help with this problem? Thank-you!
DB~

Answer (score 0):

Edit your torrc file inside your Tor Browser Bundle directory. Add the following line to your torrc file:

```
ExitNodes {us}
```

Also if you are not using Tor Browser Bundle and you are on linux, install if not already `tor-geoipdb` apt package.

```
sudo apt install tor-geoipdb
```